# Рисование линии Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно нарисовать линию из точек x,y в x1,y1:

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 12, Qt::DashDotLine, Qt::RoundCap));
        painter.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

1. Как передать точки x,y,x1,y1 в paintEvent()?
2. Как использовать paintEvent() в любой момент?

Comment: Почитайте про классы, переменные в классах, а также про функции (ааасобенно виртуальные). Прочтите документацию на paintEvent и Вы все поймете.

Answer (score 1):

> Как передать точки x,y,x1,y1 в paintEvent()?

Создайте нужные поля и методы для изменения тех полей.

> Как использовать paintEvent() в любой момент?

Вызывайте [update](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update)

---

Пример:

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    Widget(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        set(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    void set(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        this->x1 = x1;
        this->y1 = y1;
        this->x2 = x2;
        this->y2 = y2;

        // Перерисовка виджета, вызов paintEvent
        update();
    }

private:
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 12, Qt::DashDotLine, Qt::RoundCap));
        painter.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w(0, 0, 200, 200);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

---

**PS.** если вызывать у виджета `set`, то будут измены координаты линии и она перерисуется